# How to set up folder structure of a website to create using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, e-commerce

I want to create an E-commerce website. So it will have 2 sides. Front side of the Website & Back side (or Admin Panel). I want to create this using Codeigniter framewrok. How do I set up the folder structure of the site to maintain both sides of the site ?
The front side of the site url should be like

> http://www.mysite.com/

And the url of the back side should be like

> http://www.mysite.com/administrator/

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty simple setup that coule be handled in different ways.  I would also suggest what oso96_2000 suggested.  I have just done what I would do with the views folder.  In the views folder I would put a admin and public folder.  inside each folder is a new folder for each controller and inside that is the view for each in the controller.  Hope this makes sense.

```
application/
- controllers/
- - admin/
- - - welcome.php
- - - products.php
- - welcome.php
- - products.php
- views/
- - admin/
- - - welcome/
- - - - view1_for_welcome.php
- - - - view2_for_welcome.php
- - - products/
- - - .....
- - public/
- - - welcome/ 
- - - - view1_for_welcome.php
- - - - view2_for_welcome.php
```

and so on.  then you would have to make sure you put some checks in to make sure the user has access to admin controllers

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is what i usually do. Within the application folder of CI i have the following:

```
application/
- controllers/
- - admin/
- - - welcome.php
- - - products.php
- - welcome.php
- - products.php
- views/
```

This way i can access my normal site using the controllers on the base folder, and the admin side using the controllers on the admin folder. I also have defined my own custom controller from where i extend all the controllers on the site to apply access restriction based on user level.

Comment: and how do you put all the views? they also comes into sub folder?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like administrator is simply a class in your case - according to CI structure.

They have an [auth class](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/auth) to prevent normal people from viewing this class.

What more do you need to know?

**Thanks for the downvote.** Now after you read the CI docs or use it every day for years you know that folders mean absolutely nothing. Given the OP's request you could either create a class "administrator" in the controllers directory and restrict it by login - a class that CI provides FOR you so the work is minimal - or create a directory called administrator and provide a default route for this directory. Either way it would be restricted by the aforementioned auth class.

```
    if($this->isLogged() === false)
    {
        header("Location: ".base_url());
        exit;
    }
```

will keep anyone not logged in out. You can also assign user levels, or account types to restrict access all you want.
Simply creating folders for back end differentiation doesn't actually mean it is separated at all, or even easier to maintain. That's all up to your own organizational practices or standards, which may vary depending on the project - so don't give me a speech about how it is disorganized to have front and back end controllers in the same folder. Even a naming convention could resolve that.
"Any suggestions?" Well I gave one - just make it a controller. Plus a link to the auth docs. And I thank you again for somehow not getting it.